# cgicc html form file upload and opening uploaded file

Tags: c++, apache, tomcat

I have a JSP to upload a file which works fine. After the file has been uploaded I am trying to open the file again using the file path saved from the form data.

However, the filepath variable shows fine but the ifstream fails. If the csvFileName variable is set manually to path + file name it works fine. Doing this on a MAC and trying to avoid using boost library.

```
form_iterator two = cgi.getElement("csvFileName");
csvFileName=two->getValue();
form_iterator three = cgi.getElement("csvFilePath");
filePath = three->getValue();
csvFileName.c_str();
ifstream thefile;
thefile.open(csvFileName);
cout << "Filename is: " << csvFileName << endl;
if (thefile.is_open())
{
    cout << "<H1>It's working</H1>" << endl;
    while ( getline (thefile,line) )
{
  cout << line << '\n';
}
   thefile.close();
}
else 
{
    cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
}
```

Comment: this is not JSP.....why is it marked as JSP???

Comment: The html form data is coming from a jsp to the cgi application using a cgicc library.